# Canonical links and paging

Tags: seo, canonical-link

Google has been pushing its new [canonical link](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html) feature, I agree it is really useful. Now instead of having a ton of entry points in to an area you can have one entry.

I was wondering, does this feature play nice with paging?

For example: I have this [page](http://community.mediabrowser.tv/permalinks/154/iso-always-detected-as-a-movie-when-checking-metadata) which has 8 pages of content, if I specify the canonical of http://community.mediabrowser.tv/permalinks/154/iso-always-detected-as-a-movie-when-checking-metadata for the page, will there be any undesired side effects? Will this be better overall? Will this mean that a hit on page 5 will take users to page 1?

Answer (score 2):

When specifying a canonical URL, it should have substantially the same content.  Pages 2-8 have different content.  Yes, if Google were to honor your canonical link on page 5, it would send users to page 1.

You *should* use the canonical link on page 1 so that Google knows that http://community.mediabrowser.tv/topics/154 and http://community.mediabrowser.tv/topics/154?page=1&response_type=3 are the same as http://community.mediabrowser.tv/permalinks/154/iso-always-detected-as-a-movie-when-checking-metadata

You may also want to put canonical links on the other pages so Google knows that http://community.mediabrowser.tv/topics/154?page=5 is the same as http://community.mediabrowser.tv/topics/154?page=5&response_type=3

Answer (score 0):

You should only add canonical links on pages with *identical content*. For example, a set of links presented in a different order: sorted by date or alphabetically.

In your case all pages have different content (albeit representing several pages of the same article or conversation thread). Which means **you don't need to canonicalize them.**

Still if you do, all that happens is that Google gives more priority to the first page, rather than the other pages *when displaying them in search results.*

**Canonical links do not affect your visitors.** They only *suggest* priority and possible duplicate content to bots.

More info from Google [here](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=139394)